# Simple JSON object, parsing text with regular expressions

Tags: regex

I'm trying to parse a simple JSON object.

`{"difficult:name and value with commas":"99,9%;100,00%","b":"very important value","date":"01/01/2023 21:00:00","object members":4}`

My pattern`"([^\[\]\{\}]+)":"*([^\[\]\{\}]+)"*` doesn't return the result I expect.

By excluding the symbols `"[]{}"`, I want to exclude values that contain arrays or objects, and I need just a simple value pair.

I'd like to have four matches and two submatches (name,value) for each match.

| match | submatch1 | submatch2 | comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "difficult:name and value with commas":"99,9%;100,00%" | difficult:name and value with commas | 99,9%;100,00% | name and a string value I'd like to get without covering quotes "", but It's a guess that values may contain inner quotes |
| "b":"very important value" | b | very important value | also, it can be a comma inside the value, if it's not restricted by JSON standard |
| "date":"01/01/2023 21:00:00" | date | 01/01/2023 21:00:00 |  |
| "object members":4 | object members | 4 |  |

This is the result of my torment at https://regex101.com/:

[image]

I use VBA, but it's more about the pattern.

Comment: @InSync, thank you very much for the link. It is not answering the question, but a very good solution as well. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may work:

```
"([^"]+)":("([^"]+)"|([^,]+))(?=,|})
```

This how you could use it in Python:

```py
import re

json_str = '{"difficult:name and value with commas":"99,9%;100,00%","b":"very important value","date":"01/01/2023 21:00:00","object members":4}'
pattern = r'"([^"]+)":("([^"]+)"|([^,]+))(?=,|})'
matches = re.findall(pattern, json_str)

for match in matches:
    key = match[0]
    value = match[2] if match[2] else match[3]
    print(f'Key: {key}, Value: {value}')
```

You can check it out at [here](https://regex101.com/r/wmbsMu/1)

But Parsing JSON using a dedicated JSON parser is generally faster and more efficient than using regular expressions.

Here is a example of how you could parse JSON in Python:

```py
import json

json_str = '{"difficult:name and value with commas":"99,9%;100,00%","b":"very important value","date":"01/01/2023 21:00:00","object members":4}'

data = json.loads(json_str)
for key, value in data.items():
    print(f'Key: {key}, Value: {value}')
```

Comment: this works, thank you. It gives an additional value, but it's ok for me. Thank you!

Comment: @Mik If you're using PHP/PCRE you could use a [branch reset](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html) to spare one group ([updated demo](https://regex101.com/r/gL2JKp/1)).

Comment: @Mik if it works for you can make it as answer but i would suggest you use a json parser instead of using regex

Comment: Thank you. I'm still thinking about the to parse )

Comment: I have added a example of how you could use json parser in python.

Comment: I would add that not only is it potentially faster and more efficient, but it's also more accurrate and not error-prone.